# Using an image from assets/images in Bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Regarding Example 6 from [this](https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/KwYGwq) pen, I need to use an image stored in assets/images rather than one obtained via a href link as in Example 6. It looks like code changes are needed both in the CSS and in the HTML but, being a newcomer to Rails, I have not been able to figure out what they must be.

First, there's this HTML:

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="http://disputebills.com">Brand Text
        </a>
```

located, here:

```
      <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar6">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="http://disputebills.com">Brand Text
    </a>
  </div>
```

and then there is the a CSS code, here:

```
.example6 .navbar-brand{ 

    .example6 .navbar-brand{ 

    background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/candidbusiness/image/upload/v1455406304/dispute-bills-chicago.png) center / contain no-repeat;
  width: 200px;

}
```

I tried changing the CSS to

```
    background: <%= image_tag("myPETS_logo_36_48.png", class: "navbar-brand", id: "navbar-logo") %> center / contain no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
```

but even if that part is correct, it doesn't work without correcting the current HTML code,

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="http://disputebills.com">Brand Text
```

So what's a fella to do to get ane image from assets/images rather than via a href link?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly; you want to place the (dynamic) image url, into the CSS. To do that, you'll have to solve it inline, like this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand text-hide" href="http://disputebills.com" style="background: url('<%= image_url('myPETS_logo_36_48.png') %>') center / contain no-repeat;" > Brand Text </a>
```

`image_tag` creates an `img` tag, but you're actually looking for the helper that generates the path or url for the image. See [rails 5.0+ documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) and/or [older rails documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper) for more information.

Alternatively, you could solve it by placing the image in the `/public` folder and referencing it straight from the CSS, as shown by @Sebastian-Palma.

Images in the public folder are available from the project root, so, no image path helper is necessary and it would simply be:

```
.navbar-brand {
  background: url("myPETS_logo_36_48.png") center / contain no-repeat;
}
```